# Spring RestTemplate - Log on request sometimes hangs awaiting response

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I use a rest template in a Java client to log onto a server and receive required headers to upgrade a connection to a secure websocket.

here is my code:

```
private static void loginAndSaveJsessionIdCookie(final String user, final String password, final HttpHeaders headersToUpdate) {
        String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/websocket-services/login.html";
        new RestTemplate().execute(url, HttpMethod.POST,
                new RequestCallback() {
                    @Override 
                    public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                        System.out.println("start login attempt");
                        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                        map.add("username", user);
                        map.add("password", password);
                        new FormHttpMessageConverter().write(map, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, request);
                    }
                },
                new ResponseExtractor<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                        System.out.println("got login repsonse");
                        headersToUpdate.add("Cookie", response.getHeaders().getFirst("Set-Cookie"));
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }
```

This usually works, but occasionally (especially after the websocket connection has timed out) there is no response from the server and my client stops responding while the method hangs awaiting the response.

Could anyone suggest a fix or work around for this ? As it causes the client to freeze completely, requiring a force close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To async any code threading is the best way and you can use the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)
to specify any timeout you wish to have. Following two options are available as per your need (pls chk API to know difference between them) :-

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks,
                                  long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException;
```

OR

```
<T> T invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks,
                    long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException;
```

Comment: thanks, will give this a try. i hadnt thought to put into its own execution thread.